# Remember the Milk Desktop client

Tags: software-rec, gtd, rememberthemilk

I'm a long-time fan of Remember The Milk for task management but have started to find myself turned off by the service because of the lack of good desktop clients.

This [question has been asked a once or twice in the past](https://superuser.com/questions/17577/best-remember-the-milk-client-for-windows-xp), but I still havn't found a suitable client that supports all the features the web interface has. Ultimately I am looking for a feature-full and stable application that does not require a web browser.

Here are what I've tried so far:

- [Tasque](http://live.gnome.org/Tasque)

  Didn't even work when I installed it ('Taskque.exe has stopped working...') - from what I can tell from the website it only has basic task management features at the moment. Does appear to have a roadmap and active developers but I can't even test it properly.
- [Milkify](http://www.milkify.com/about/)

  Buggy. Moving between windows keeps generating exceptions - clearly not a finished product. Has some really nice features like keyboard commands but it takes three attempts to move from a task to the list view, and you normally have to fiddle around with the mouse for a while to get it to work. Doesn't appear to have any active developers.
- [App For the Milk](http://www.chrillo.info/apps/app-for-the-milk/)

  I'm using this primarily at the moment and it has most of what I want, apart from tags. The UI is a little  strange and causes a couple of annoying bugs but it is possible to work around them. Completed tasks disappear to some void and are unretrievable with the app unless you uncomplete them on the website.The keyboard commands are not great either. Doesn't appear to have any active developers.
- [Milksync for Outlook + Outlook](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/milksync/outlook/)

  A bit of a hack really - no proper notes support (if you want multiple notes you have to create them somewhere else then sync), tags/lists are strange and don't fit in with Outlooks own task categorisation model. Supported by Remember The Milk themselves but overall not what I want (also I only use Outlook on my work machine, not my home machine or laptop).

So, can anyone recommend a better desktop app? Or, has task management transcended RTM and moved on to some newer, shinier service with better desktop support? I'm open to suggestions for alternative software/services if the latter is the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best 'Remember the milk' client for Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/17577/best-remember-the-milk-client-for-windows-xp)

Comment: @techie007: If you read the post you will see that I've referenced that very question.

Comment: I realize that, but it's still the same question, IMO. But that's why closing needs more than 1 vote. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the Google Chrome application feature. It wraps everything up into a nice window that feels native.

Login to your RTM account, and follow [these instructions](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95710). If you want offline access, enable [Google Gears](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/googlegears/).

Comment: Can't say I'm totally convinced - one of my biggest gripes with the RTM web interface is that it is a bit clunky. Being a Chrome user though I will however give it a try and see how it goes - thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Update: Well I've been using it for today and while it is not perfect, it does give me all the features and works more like a desktop application. Probably the best I can get at the moment, thanks emb1995!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this Adobe Air app, which means it runs in Mac, Windows and Linux.
I'll try it right now but it says it features Online-Offline sync, which doesn't work on Chrome since Chrome 12 I guess (no Gears support!).

http://www.chrillo.info/apps/app-for-the-milk/

> App for the milk is a desktop client for the remember the milk
>   webservice that lets you quickly manage your tasks from your desktop
>   even when you are offline and sync the next time you are connected to
>   the internet.

Comment: Yup, that's App for the Milk which I did use for a while (and mention in the question). Unfortunately it doesn't have a full feature set and hasn't been getting a lot of updates recently, but I did like it.

Comment: Dude, he mentioned it right in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two apps that I am currently investigating capable of Syncing with RTM. My requirements are 1. Cross platform (Linux & Windows) and 2. Ability to connect with Note Taking App (Preferably Tomboy)

1. [Tasque](http://live.gnome.org/Tasque) as you mentioned
2. [GTG](http://gtg.fritalk.com/)

GTG is quite feature rich but currently the Windows port is in the initial stages of development. I have currently settled doen for Tasque.